# Implementing 3D-Touch with swift on View

Tags: ios, swift, gestures, 3dtouch, force-touch

Im experimenting with the 3D-Touch/Force-Touch these days and Im new to iOS Development.

If I search for 3D-Touch in Swift - I always find something about Peek & Pop or Quick-Actions on Home Screen.

I want to ask, if its possible to initiate a 3D-Touch somewhere on my View? For example - Every time I make a 3D-Touch, a rectangle will be shown on that specific Touch-position. And after that make some other gestures with the rectangle.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look at the `touchesBegan`, `moved`, `ended` and `canceled` methods of `UIView`, by overriding those you can get the touch object and get the force property.

Comment: I did use [this](https://github.com/FlexMonkey/DeepPressGestureRecognizer) Gesture Recognizer with some minor tweaks for little customizations I needed

Comment: Is there maybe a more elegegant solution, instead of the force property? Because its not working well - sometimes it shows 0 when i make a force touch.